# Use `created_at` instead of `inserted_at`

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

I want to use an old Rails MySQL database/table without changing it with a new Elixir application. Obviously I run into the `created_at`and `inserted_at` problem. https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#timestamps/1 says that I can solve it. But I can't get it to work.

Here's what I do:

```
mix phoenix.new address_book --database mysql
cd address_book
mix phoenix.gen.html User users first_name last_name
mix phoenix.server
```

**web/models/user.ex**

```
defmodule AddressBook.User do
  use AddressBook.Web, :model

  schema "users" do
    field :first_name, :string
    field :last_name, :string

    timestamps([{:created_at,:updated_at}])
  end
[...]
```

But than I get the following error:

[image: Screenshot]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't calling the timestamps function with the correct argument. It takes options, so it should be either:

```
timestamps(inserted_at: :created_at)
```

Or:

```
timestamps([{inserted_at: :created_at}])
```

You are calling:

```
timestamps(created_at: :updated_at)
```

Since there is no check for the `created_at` option, this does not change the timestamps being used.

You can configure this for all your schemas by using:

```
  @timestamps_opts inserted_at: :created_at
```

In your web.ex file (in the schema section).

Comment: Where exactly should @timestamps_opts be defined? Can't find a schema sectio.

Comment: put it in a line just after your `use Ecto.Schema`. like this: `@timestamps_opts [inserted_at: :created_at]`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer above, the best way to set this across a context is:

```
defmodule MyApp.Schema do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      use Ecto.Schema
      @timestamps_opts inserted_at: :created_at
    end
  end
end
```

Then, instead of having to define that in each schema, you can just `use MyApp.Schema`.

I use this pattern in my phoenix app that uses a coexisting db-schema generated by rails.

https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html